# R: How can I lower the amount of levels in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe with over 40 levels, I want to make it 4 levels. The important variables are "ecommerce", "technology", and "consumer goods", everything else I want to fall under "other". How can I make it into 4 levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forcats::fct_other()` was designed for exactly this:

```
library(forcats)

fct_other(my_var, keep = c('ecommerce', 'technology', 'consumer goods'))
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use `%in%` to check :

```
df$column_name <- as.character(df$column_name)
df$column_name[!df$column_name %in% c('ecommerce', 'technology', 'consumer goods')] <- 'Other'
```

---

If you want to keep the column as factors :

```
levels(df$column_name) <- c(levels(df$column_name), 'Other')
df$column_name[!df$column_name %in% c('ecommerce', 'technology', 'consumer goods')] <- 'Other'
```

Comment: I want "ecommerce", "technology" and "consumer goods" to also be levels, sorry I didn't make that clear! So I want to make it 4 levels, not binary. @RonakShah

Comment: @sjoelly The result is not binary in both the options. It will give you 4 levels if you use second option.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra column using your new categories with "ifelse" in a dplyr chain.

```
newdf <- df%>%
mutate(newcategories=factor(ifelse(allcategories %in% c("ecommerce", "technology", "consumer goods"), allcategories, "Other")))
```

This would allow you to check the frequency of categories assigned to "Other" :

```
newdf%>%
group_by(newcategories,allcategories)%>%
filter(newcategories=="Other")%>%
count()%>%
arrange(desc(n))
```